# Understanding halving algorithm in online learning

Tags: machine-learning, learning-theory

I am working through *"Understanding Machine Learning Theory"* by Shai Shalev-Schwartz. In the chapter "Online learning" I came across the halving algorithm, the author uses the following algorithmic pseudo-code for the algorithm
[image]
I am having difficulty understanding authors intention from the highlighted portion. Here $\mathcal{H}$ is the hypothesis class, $V_{t}$ is the version space at iteration t, $(x_t,y_t)\in S$ are samples from the set provided by the oracle. We also assume that $h^{*}\in\mathcal{H}$ (realizability).

**Attempt**: My guess is the prediction is based on majority vote from hypotheses in version space, but I don't see where he is pruning the version space using the majority vote? What am I missing? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prediction is the value of $r$ which maximizes the quantity
$$ | \{ h \in V_t : h (\mathbf{x}_t) = r \} |. $$
This is the number of surviving hypotheses (belonging to $V_t$) which predict $r$ on the current point ($\mathbf{x}_t$). Equivalently, we ask all hypotheses in $V_t$ for their opinion on $\mathbf{x}_t$. If more answer $0$, we predict $0$. If more answer $1$, we predict $1$. In case of a tie, we (arbitrarily) predict $1$. In other words, we take majority vote on the opinions of the hypotheses in $V_t$ on $\mathbf{x}_t$.

After seeing the true label, we throw out all hypothesis which were wrong; this is the meaning of the update line, which sets $V_{t+1}$ to contain all hypotheses $h$ in $V_t$ such that $h(\mathbf{x}_t) = y_t$, where $y_t$ is the true label of $\mathbf{x}_t$.

Each time the algorithm is wrong, at least half of the hypotheses in $V_t$ were wrong, so $V_{t+1}$ is at least twice as small as $V_t$. So after $\log_2 |\mathcal{H}|$ wrong answers, we are left with a single hypothesis, which must be the true one. This is why this algorithm makes at most $\log_2 |\mathcal{H}|$ mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Yuval. My follow up question is how is the algorithm using the prediction to prune the version space?

Comment: The last line prunes away all hypotheses which do not correspond to the true label.

Comment: In that case wouldn't a more accurate mathematical representation be $$ V_{t+1} = \{h\in V_t: h(x_t)=p_t \wedge h(x_t)=y_t\}$$ ?

Comment: No, that would be a *wrong* description. What if $p_t \neq y_t$? You will be left with no hypotheses!

Comment: I think I understand. I was not thinking about what constitutes a mistake, $p_t \neq y_t$ so for every mistake atleast half the hypothesis are pruned which gives better bound on mistakes after some iterations than choosing a random hypothesis from version space.